# The input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm new into c# programming and I can't get this code. The error I get is

> input string was not in correct format.

I know it's a duplicate question, but what I have found so far, didnt' helped me much. I'm using the code below in order to insert some data into a mssql database.

```
public void btnAdauga_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAutocar", txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", txtIDTip.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", int.Parse(cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(val + "Autocarul a fost adaugat cu succes!");
            con.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception er){MessageBox.Show(er.Message);}
}
```

The insert statement: `string insert = "INSERT INTO Autocare (IDAutocar, IDTipAutocar, TipAutocar) VALUES (@IDAutocar, @IDTipAutocar, @TipAutocar)";`

The error is at this line of code: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", int.Parse(cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()));` Could anyone enlighten me what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: What is a value of `cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()` at this moment?

Comment: It is probably due to cmbTip.SelectedValue does not have a number that could be converted to int.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - the combo is populated with some values using a select statement

Comment: @rrrrdc It looks exactly like it populates it with non-number values. That's why `int.Parse` fails and throws exception.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - and what should I do?

Comment: @rrrrdc Such a strange question. When you click your button, what is a value of your combobox? If it is not a number, then something's wrong with your model, database or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) function instead of Int.Parse and handle parsing exceptions before that line. Like this:

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAutocar", txtID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDTipAutocar", txtIDTip.Text);

            int tipAutocar = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString(), out tipAutocar))
            {
                //if successful
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", tipAutocar));
            }
            else
            {
                //if not successful, do sth else
            }

            int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(val + "Autocarul a fost adaugat cu succes!");
            con.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your combobox contains int values as strings, then use

```
int.Parse(cmbTip.Text);
```

If you want the index of the selected text, then use

```
int.Parse(cmbTip.SelectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Yeldar suggestion, I have removed `int.Parse` and use only `combo.SelectedValue` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug properly with breakpoints and step into the code, and in debug menu add the variables of interest in the "Watch" window or look for them in the "Locals" window while debugging. [for eg `cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()` ]
2. As pointed by others `cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString()` could be the reason for the exception.
3. for `cmbTip` even after selecting the value the error persists, or the `selectedValue` comes as `NULL`, try to using `SelectedText`